# TensorFlow Device Contexts

Tags: tensorflow

I am adding new hardware to TensorFlow and I am having trouble with the Device Contexts.

Just to make sure I understand their purpose, from the code, they appear to manage the devices and data for a given node in the compute graph. Namely, the Devices for the input data and output of data are specified in the Device Context and the Executor handles passing Tensors back and forth between these devices. Every OpKernelContext appears to contain a Device Context that governs the particular execution of that given kernel.

Currently for my new hardware, the Device Contexts are all null which is ultimately causing a segfault. Per the style of the existing C++, I would expect that there are macros that allow me to "register" the Device Contexts for a particular Device Type (ie. GPU, CPU), but I can't find these. My question is then, how do I get proper Device Contexts to be added to the OpKernelContext's as they are created for my device.

Note that I have not written a Device Context class specific to my hardware. I noticed that ThreadPoolDevice does not appear to have a DeviceContext implementation specific to it. I assume this is because the base class DeviceContext is implemented for ThreadPools.

I would appreciate any clarification on DeviceContexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DeviceContext](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/73ced9d797056c7e67a06ed2098dd809d85ec44a/tensorflow/core/framework/device_base.h#L64) 
objects
serve two purposes:

1. At the moment, there's some StreamExecutor-specific bits that most callers probably can ignore (gpu::Stream / MaintainLifetime) because they are specific to GPU.

   You need a handle to the underlying device resources in OpKernels, and the DeviceContext object holds the "stream" object that is used to compute on.

   We have yet to implement an opaque handle in DeviceContext that other devices should implement as their resource, but that's what would be needed.  So that's a TODO before we could get non StreamExecutor-based devices to work, unfortunately.
2. The other component is code to handle copying to and from the device to CPU.  You are right that the DeviceContexts don't exist for CPU, because CPU is the host device and doesn't need to be treated specially from this point of view.

   But as an example, we can take a look at the code for GPU.
   [`tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu_device_context.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cee7cdd23ddd518f452465f50021049faec4e88e/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu_device_context.h) is an example of the GPU device context, which implements the DeviceContext interface.  The implementation of the interface is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cee7cdd23ddd518f452465f50021049faec4e88e/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_util_platform_specific.cc), which delegates to the code in the GPUUtil class for actually performing the memcopies.  It happens to use the StreamExecutor framework to handle the underlying copies, but your own device would use whatever APIs you have for copying to and from host to device.

   If you want to copy from device to device, there's a special registration for this.  An example for GPU to GPU is:
   [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f974e8d0c2420c6f7e2a2791febb4781a266823f/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_util.cc#L190)
   for the implementation, and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f974e8d0c2420c6f7e2a2791febb4781a266823f/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_util.cc#L255) for the registration of that function.

At some point we might refactor this to be a bit cleaner, so the registrations are all uniform (CPU to device, device to CPU, device to device).  At the moment it's a bit ad hoc.

So it's going to be a work in progress at the moment to support other devices, but we are happy to work with you and others to flesh out this support.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! So I think on the to-do list first is to create that "opaque handle" in DeviceContexts. I could start working on that if you give me details of what you are looking for. You could start a Git issue or something I can start working on.

Comment: Where is the `register_gpu_gpu_copy` defined/used? I can't find it anywhere in TensorFlow. I assume it is some sort of macro, but I can't find any macros that appear to match it. Regex grepping isn't giving much either