# TensorFlow Device Contexts, Streams and Context Switching

Tags: tensorflow

In the [GPUDevice](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc#L264) code, I noticed that one [GPUDeviceContext](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc#L308) is made per stream.

Is the purpose of this so that every context can control one OpKernelContext and then as the various streams need to be executed, then the contexts can just be switched which handles pushing different data/code onto the GPU and then executing.

Do the various streams get registered as different devices (ie. '/gpu:0' and '/gpu:1')?

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399890/tensorflow-device-contexts), ThreadPoolDevice's don't have contexts, but if I were to add contexts into ThreadPoolDevice, would they fit best as a sort of ThreadContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GPU, we maintain a few streams for execution: a compute stream (on which most computational kernels run), and some memcopy streams (for executing memcopies between host and device and vice versa).  This is done to overlap communication and computation on GPU devices, but is particular to the way that we use GPUs.  One could easily also just create one GPU stream for all computation and communication and it would be correct, although slower.

We want to give the computation stream to kernels that do computation, and the memcopy stream to the kernels that do copying.  We create a GPUDeviceContext object for each stream, and then pass the right device context object to the OpKernelContext.

So the particular implementations here reflect the properties of the asynchronous hardware device (GPU), which is why the ThreadPoolDevice doesn't have these sorts of mechanisms.  On CPU all computation is synchronous, so there is no need for an abstraction such as streams.

The execution model of the custom hardware will likely determine what kind of state and management a custom device support will require in TensorFlow.

Comment: I was also concerned about the actual initialization of the device contexts, but it appears that you initialize them in the constructor of the `BaseGPUDevice` and then hold them until you run `FillContextMap`. Ultimately, I am wondering why the execution engine had null contexts. I assume this is because I was not pushing them into the context map. Can you confirm that this would cause a nullptr issue?   https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/73ced9d797056c7e67a06ed2098dd809d85ec44a/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc#L338